# Compute column value with CASE syntax

Tags: mysql

I am pretty confused and absolutely not sure if this is the right way.
In the example below I am trying to check if the promotion type is 1 ( percentage e.g. 10% ) or 2 ( hard price e.g 10 EUR ) and compute the price after it and that only if `main_product_id IS NOT NULL`. Otherwise the price stays the same.

```
SELECT p.price
FROM product as p
LEFT JOIN promotion_product as pp ON p.id=pp.main_product_id 
LEFT JOIN promotion as pr ON pp.promo_id=pr.id
(
CASE
    WHEN pp.main_product_id IS NOT NULL THEN 
        CASE 
            WHEN pr.type=1 THEN p.price = p.price - (p.price * pr.value/100)
            WHEN pr.type=2 THEN p.price = p.price - pr.value 
        END
END
)
```

What I get as error is:

```
#1305 - FUNCTION pr.id does not exist
```

This is pretty clear I know. But how to compute the new price and is it possible with `CASE` syntax ?

product table :

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| category_id    | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| brand_id       | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| sort           | int(11)      | NO   |     | 999     |                |
| enable         | tinyint(1)   | NO   | MUL | 2       |                |
| product_number | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| price          | float        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| quantity       | float        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| rating         | tinyint(4)   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

promotion table:

```
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| start_date | timestamp  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| end_date   | timestamp  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| type       | tinyint(4) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| value      | float      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| enable     | tinyint(4) | NO   |     | 2       |                |
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

promotion_product table:

```
+-----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| promo_id        | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| product_id      | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| main_product_id | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Just put `CASE` statement in `SELECT` column list.

Comment: Yep. It works like that. But as result I get `0` for all the rows. And the prices are definitely not `0`. I am doing something wrong for sure.

Comment: We cannot see your data, so we cannot answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CASE...WHEN...THEN` expressions are for use in `SELECT` clauses. You have yours wrapped in parentheses at the end of your query. Because your query looks like `pr.id(yadda yadda)` MySQL thinks `pr.id` should be a function. It isn't, so MySQL throws your error.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT p.price, 
           CASE
               WHEN pr.type=1 THEN p.price = p.price - (p.price * pr.value/100)
               WHEN pr.type=2 THEN p.price = p.price - pr.value 
               ELSE p.price
           END promoted_price
  FROM product as p
  LEFT JOIN promotion_product as pp ON p.id=pp.main_product_id 
  LEFT JOIN promotion as pr ON pp.promo_id=pr.id
```

I refactored your case expressions so it's not nested. The `ELSE` clause deals with the default cases where `pr.type` isn't `1` or `2`, and where the ON clauses of your left joins don't match anything.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN promotion as pr`  may as well be 'JOIN promotion as pr` and then it would fall back to p.price. The `left`-ness of the query isn't utilized.

Comment: Thank you very much! Will try it as soon as I get home!

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I will approach your goal:

```
SELECT
    IF(pp.main_product_id IS NOT NULL,
       CASE
           WHEN pr.type = 1 THEN p.price - (p.price * pr.value / 100)
           WHEN pr.type = 2 THEN p.price - pr.value
           ELSE p.price -- Added a default case.
       END,
       p.price) AS finalPrice
FROM
    product AS p
LEFT JOIN
    promotion_product AS pp ON p.id = pp.main_product_id 
LEFT JOIN
    promotion AS pr ON pp.promo_id = pr.id
```

Note also, that you have `start_date` and `end_date` on your `promotion` table that you are currently ignoring.

Comment: Yes, yes. I will add them later. Just trying to figure out how to construct this type of query.